# Create Spinner dropdown list in nativescript-angular app

Tags: android, angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

How can I create dropdown list spinner in nativescript angular application that can be used for both the platform android and ios

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxS9J.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [DropDown](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-drop-down) plugin

```
tns plugin add nativescript-drop-down
```

**Note:** The DropDown in the image is native android component, there is no iOS equivalent out of the box which may give you exact same look and feel.

**Edit:**

The DropDown plugin is no longer updated and transferred to [ProPlugins](https://npm.proplugins.org/-/web/detail/@proplugins/nativescript-drop-down)

```
tns plugin add @proplugins/nativescript-drop-down
```

Comment: I added this plugin to my project but giving error                                                                       ERROR in node_modules/nativescript-drop-down/drop-down.d.ts(16,33): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'data/observable-array'. using angular 8.1,nativescript 5.4

Comment: Install the latest version from pro plugins.